# My Primary Domain Controller does not work with other laptop

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, networking, ubuntu-10.04

I have configured my primary domain controller in Ubuntu 11.10.

To make sure that it worked, I used a Windows 7 client in my friend laptop and I can successfully log in as a user from my domain.

But when I try to test another laptop it failed with this notification.

> An Active Directory Domain Controller (AD DC) for the domain"MYDOMAIN" could not be contacted. Ensure that the domain name
>   is typed correctly. if the name is correct.click Details for trouble
>   shooting information.

What's wrong? I configured the failed client same as the client that was success, and I typed the domain in correctly.

Comment: Do you have samba configured to automatically add the machine accounts?  Did you set up DNS correctly as per the Samba PDC guide?  Perhaps [edit] and add your smb.conf and dns settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if your DC is responding on port 53 (default port for windows-based DC), if not this could be the problem.

Comment: how to check it?? really i am very confuse about DC?